# What pattern do you use for executing generic steps on a pool of machines

Tags: build, build-automation, hudson

I'm trying to figure out how to model my build process in hudson.  At present most of our hudson builds are somewhat hard coded in that the build process is series of steps and we have one process per branch.

I have another build system that has many active branches and each build has a series of integration tests which require a suit of machines to execute.   As I migrate from the home grown to hudson I'm not quite sure what's the right way to model this to keep sustainability costs and build times to a minimum

### Here's my basic build:

- create workspace
- compile, link, package
- transfer artifacts to test systems
- invoke test harness on multiple systems to handle installation and acceptance tests
- collect results
- publish results

I'd like the integration part to be a group of generic machines (perhaps an elastic group) which can handle integration-tests for any branch.  I want to run as much in parallel as possible to keep my build times low.  It looks like the best way to execute in parallel on hudson is to break up steps into jobs and use the Parameterized Trigger Plugin to customize the generic jobs.

So, i'd have two main jobs: build, test

I could have on build job per branch and a generic test job.  The build job would use Parameterized Trigger Plugin to call the test job and provide the location of the build artifacts.  The test job would call a series of jobs in parallel passing down parameters for branch, artifact.
test
   test-client-install (params: artifact location, branch)
   test-server-install (params: artifact location, branch)
   test-run (params: client machine, server machine)
   join - collect results (params: client machine, server machine)

Each of the test-* jobs would pull a slave out of the group of slaves and execute.  I'm not quite sure how to inform the slaves running the client and server jobs how to find each other nor am I sure how to reserve them from the pool and release them back into it.

I guess, I could have a write properties to a common share and have the sub jobs use that for inter-job communication.

Has anyone created this kind of complex setup in hudson, or is this usually done in another system with which hudson interacts (hudson + STAF with STAF managing resources)?

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts. The fewer jobs you have, the easier it is to maintain them. The more jobs you have, the more flexible you are and you can run more in parallel. Since you emphasized fast build times, have a look at the [join plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Join+Plugin), to run a few jobs in parallel and when all of these are finished to go on with another job in that chain.

If your server is big enough, you can experiment a little bit with the [clone workspace plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin). It will help you to reduce the need for manual copying files between jobs and the need for the parametrized trigger plugin.

Reserving a slave is easy. You can group the slaves with labels. In your job you define what label you node has to have in order to execute your job. A node can have more than one label and your job can be bound to more than one label. This way, Hudson decides where to put your job depending on availability. If your slaves have more than one build queue, they can run two jobs in parallel. I haven't used the [locks-and-latches plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Locks+and+Latches+plugin) for synchronizing across nodes. So I don't know if locks are only per node or for the whole Hudson installation. Latches are not supported yet. If you need to ensure that two jobs need to run on the same slave, try to combine them, otherwise you will lose the advantage of Hudson to distribute your jobs freely over the available nodes.